# How do I sum a set of vectors and produce a new vector in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark's Java API, and read a lot of data with following schema:

```
profits (Array of Double values):
--------------------------------- 
[1.0,2.0,3.0] 
[2.0,3.0,4.0] 
[4,0,6.0]
```

Once I have a dataframe, I want to compute a new vector which is the sum of all the vectors:

```
Result:
[7.0,11.0,7.0]
```

I see some examples online on doing this in Scala and Python, but nothing for Java.